# Qt5. Как временно отключить генерацию событий от дочерних виджетов?

Tags: qt, qt5, любой-язык

Пишу виджет редактора параметров и возникла проблема с генерацией событий от дочерних виджетов.

Сам виджет подписывается на изменение дочерних и пересылает события выше.
Допустим, редактор содержит пару `QLineEdit`:

```py
class Editor(QWidget):
    paramsChanged = Signal(str, str)
    
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__build_ui()
    
    def __build_ui(self):
        self.__a = QLineEdit()
        self.__b = QLineEdit();
        
        box = QVBoxLayout()
        
        box.addWidget(self.__a)
        box.addWidget(self.__b)
        self.__a.textChanged.connect(self.__on_paramChanged)
        self.__b.textChanged.connect(self.__on_paramChanged)
        
        self.setLayout(box)
        
    def __on_paramChanged(self):
        self.paramsChanged.emit(self.__a.text(), self.__b.text())
    
    def setParams(self, a, b):
        self.__a.setText(a)
        self.__b.setText(b)
```

При программной установке значений дочерние виджеты генерируют события "изменено".

```py
editor.setParams("a", "b")
```

Лог:

```bash
changed a 
changed a b
```

Собственно вопрос:
Как на время загрузки параметров(`Editor::setParams`) отключить генерацию событий от дочерних виджетов?

Полный код на `Python + PySide2`

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Editor(QWidget):
    paramsChanged = Signal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__build_ui()

    def __build_ui(self):
        self.__a = QLineEdit()
        self.__b = QLineEdit();

        box = QVBoxLayout()

        box.addWidget(self.__a)
        box.addWidget(self.__b)
        self.__a.textChanged.connect(self.__on_paramChanged)
        self.__b.textChanged.connect(self.__on_paramChanged)

        self.setLayout(box)

    def __on_paramChanged(self):
        self.paramsChanged.emit(self.__a.text(), self.__b.text())

    def setParams(self, a, b):
        self.__a.setText(a)
        self.__b.setText(b)


def on_change(a, b):
    print("changed", a, b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    editor = Editor()
    editor.paramsChanged.connect(on_change)

    editor.show()

    editor.setParams("a", "b")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, оформите пожалуйста как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заблокировать сигналы от наследника QObject (включая виджеты):

```
QObject.blockSignals(True)
```

Разблокировать, соответственно:

```
QObject.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Коротко и понятно `+`

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к ответу от [Alexander Chernin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235611/alexander-chernin)

Если при наложении блокировки она была уже активирована , то вызов
`object->blockSignals(false);` ее снимет, что может сломать вызывающий код.

Например:

```cpp
// Наш класс
class MyObject: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setValues(/* */);
    // ...
signals:
    void valueChanged();
    // ...
};

void MyObject::setValues(/* */)
{
    blockSignals(true);
    // ...
    // какой то код для установки значения в дочерние объекты
    // ...
    blockSignals(false); // безусловная разблокировка

    emit valueCanged(); // генерация сигнала
}
```

Вызывающий код

```cpp
constructor()
{
    object = new MyObject(this);
    connect(object, ...);
}

void updateObject()
{
    object->blockSignals(true);
    // ...
    object->setValues(...);
    // < тут сигналы от object уже разблокированы
    // ...
    object->blockSignals(false);
}
```

[`QObject::blockSignals`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) возвращает предыдущее состояние блокировки сигналов для данного объекта, что позволяет восстанавливать предыдущее состояние.

То есть код методов `MyObject::setValues` и `updateObject` нужно модифицировать:

```cpp
void MyObject::setValues(/* */)
{
    auto state = blockSignals(true); // сохранение старого состояния
    // ...
    // какой то код для установки значения в дочерние объекты
    // ...
    blockSignals(state); // восстановить состояние блокировки

    emit valueCanged(); // генерация сигнала
}

void updateObject()
{
    auto state = object->blockSignals(true);
    // ...
    object->setValues(...);
    // OK: сигналы от object еще заблокированы
    // ...
    object->blockSignals(state);
}
```

Для того чтобы не забывать об этом можно использовать вспомогательный класс [`QSignalBlocker`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html).
Его алгоритм и метод использования напоминает [`lock guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

```cpp
void updateObject()
{
    QSignalBlocker block(object); // блокировка
    // ...
    object->setValues(...);
    // ...
    // автоматическое восстановление состояния блокировки
}
```

Пример для `Python`

```py
def updateObject(self):
    _ = QSignalBlocker(self.object);

    self.object.setValues(...)
```